# How to populate the database for latest MongoDB Docker image?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Recently, I'm unable to launch a docker container based off the **mongo** image via my old set of command:

`docker run -d --rm -v ${PWD}/mydb_data:/data/db --name db mongo`

I noticed that the mongo images now have a preexisting but empty /data/db directory. Every time I try to populate some files into this /data/db directory within a container, the container fails and exits automatically. My first question is: *are there any quick fix to this problem that I missed?*

- For clarification, my *mydb_data* directory contains .index files and .wt files etc. (And as a side comment, I got this directory handed over from a previous colleague so I'm still trying to understand the setup more.)

A second question is: is it normal that I'm receiving a stream of log outputs like *below* as I try to populate mongo db inside the docker container via an alternative set of commands that attempts to create a differently named new database through `docker run -it -v ${PWD}/mydb_data:/data/db2 --name db2 mongo`?

> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.246+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.246+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.247+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.247+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.248+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.248+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.248+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-13T18:29:32.249+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"6e3da962aee5"}}
> ..........

My attempt to create a new mongo db has been going on for some hour, so I hope to check if this is on the right track.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mongo - Official Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

### Initializing a fresh instance

When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions .sh and .js that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.